# How to use NLog in xUnit tests from .NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nlog, xunit

I am trying to output some log messages from within .NET Core 3.1-based xUnit test cases by means of the NLog logging library. Logging by means of NLog works fine in my main application, but the test cases just won't output any messages.

I *think* I am doing everything suggested in this related question: [*NLog works in ASP.NET Core App but not in .NET Core xUnit Test Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534730/nlog-works-in-asp-net-core-app-but-not-in-net-core-xunit-test-project)

Somehow, though, I cannot figure out what is missing. I have reduced my code into a minimal sample that seems very straightforward, but still does not output anything:

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using System;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace UnitTests
{
    public class LoggingTest
    {
        public LoggingTest(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.output = output;
        }

        private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

        [Fact]
        public void TestLog()
        {
            var target = new MemoryTarget {Layout = "${message}"};

            LogManager.Configuration ??= new LoggingConfiguration();
            LogManager.Configuration.AddRuleForAllLevels(target);

            LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hello, World!");

            output.WriteLine("{0} line(s) logged:\n{1}", target.Logs.Count, String.Join("\n", target.Logs));
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

> 1 line(s) logged:
> Hello, World!

Actual output:

> 0 line(s) logged:

---

As one further trace, I have read in various places that NLog will only write something in .NET Core 3.1 projects if certain settings are present in a `Logging` section of the `appsettings.json` file. I think this section also had to be added to our main application's `appsettings.json` file.

I am not sure how to transfer this knowledge to the unit tests, though, as they do not appear to come with an `appsettings.json` file. I have tried copying the main `appsettings.json` file to the output directory of the unit tests (which is, I think, their execution directory when run from within ReSharper), but to no avail.

---

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the config, you need to **assign** `LogManager.Configuration`, like

```cs
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Working example:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestLog()
{
    var target = new MemoryTarget { Layout = "${message}" };

    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    config.AddRuleForAllLevels(target);
    LogManager.Configuration = config; // <-- assign here
    LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hello, World!");

    output.WriteLine("{0} line(s) logged:\n{1}", target.Logs.Count, String.Join("\n", target.Logs));

    Assert.Equal(1, target.Logs.Count);
}
```

### Bonus: tests in parallel

Bonus, if you like tests in parallel (who doesn't ;)) - create a new `LogFactory` instead of assigning the global `LogManager`.

Like this:

```
[Fact]
public void TestLogParallelSafe()
{
    var logFactory = new LogFactory();

    var target = new MemoryTarget { Layout = "${message}" };

    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    config.AddRuleForAllLevels(target);
    logFactory.Configuration = config;
    logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hello, World!");

    output.WriteLine("{0} line(s) logged:\n{1}", target.Logs.Count, String.Join("\n", target.Logs));

    Assert.Equal(1, target.Logs.Count);
}
```

Of course if other code is using the `LogManager`, you can't assert those logs.

### .NET Core integration

> As one further trace, I have read in various places that NLog will only write something in .NET Core 3.1 projects if certain settings are present in a Logging section of the appsettings.json file. I think this section also had to be added to our main application's appsettings.json file.

This is only needed when integrating with ASP.NET Core - e.g. when injection the `ILogger<T>` from Microsoft. That's is not needed here. For further reference, see [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 3 · NLog/NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. My output now arrives as expected. Let me clarify a few things, though: "you need to assign LogManager.Configuration" - well, I was already doing so: `LogManager.Configuration ??= new LoggingConfiguration();` *However*, the crucial point seems to be that I have to do this *after* adding my rules, or else NLog will not notice the new configuration. Knowing about this, I can now confirm even writing something seemingly nonsensical like `LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration;` after my `AddRuleForAllLevels` call will fix the issue in my original code.

Comment: Concerning the parallel testing, the suggestion makes a lot of sense usually, though unfortunately, "if other code is using the LogManager, you can't assert those logs." is a showstopper in my particular situation. If it were just for the test class itself, I'd already have xUnit's `ITestOutputHelper` at my disposal for logging stuff. My main rationale for wanting to use NLog is precisely that I do not want to punch holes into all of my interfaces so my test class can insert its logging references, but instead use NLog's static `GetLogger` method that I can call from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The approach proposed by Julian can be improved by implementing a specific target which writes the log entries to the output directly, without delay and without buffering all log entries in memory.

```cs
internal class TestOutputTarget: TargetWithLayout {
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public TestOutputTarget(ITestOutputHelper output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) {
        output.WriteLine(RenderLogEvent(Layout, logEvent));
    }
}

...
// In the test code
var target = new TestOutputTarget(output) { Layout = "${message}" };
```